Logic intro with specific treatment of variable assignment function
I am seeking a reference to an introductory text to first-oder logic which does one or both of the following:

Consider the variable assignment function as part of the model that also has the interpretation function for the predicates, rather than having $\mathcal{M}, v$ as parallel notions.
Let the assignment function be defined only on the set of free variables relative to a given formula, rather than all the infinitely many available variables of the language.


First bullett not very clear... Ebbinghaus uses an $S$-structure for a language $S$ made of a domain and a mapping for the symbols and the usual concept of assignment (defined for all variables). Then defines an $S$-interpretation $I$ as the a pair $(A,β)$ consisting of an $S$-structure $A$ and an assignment $β$ in $A$. Nothing different from usual...

But the issue is that, for a specific model M, we have to manage different variables assignments in order to define the satisfaction clauses for quantifiers. In order to "embed" all of them into the interpretation itself we have to list them in some order.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Re 1. Thanks for the reference. Re 2. Right, but in order to list all the relevant ones we don't need some initial assignment to be defined on all variables of the language, so if done right the quantifier satisfaction clauses should be no issue.
